# Using generic protocol, how to have different associated value in one view controller which confirms the protocol

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

The scenario is: in a view controller (say: `WorldViewController`) which confirmed the protocol (showed below), the protocol is used for pop over a content view controller.

I wish it could popover 2 different popover content view controller (let's say `TablePopoverContentVC`, `TextFieldPopoverContentVC`) in the view controller (`WorldViewController`).

But through this protocol, I can only associate to one type in a view controller.

```
protocol ShowPopoverProtocol: class {
    associatedtype PopoverContentType: PopoverBaseContent

    func showPopover(contentVc: PopoverContentType, on target: UIView, preferredWidth: CGFloat)
}

extension ShowPopoverProtocol where Self: UIViewController {

func showPopover(contentVc: PopoverContentType, on target: UIView, preferredWidth: CGFloat) {
    guard let popoverPresentation = configurePresentation(from: contentVc, preferredWidth: preferredWidth) else {
        return
    }
    popoverPresentation.sourceView = target
    popoverPresentation.sourceRect = target.bounds

    self.present(contentVc, animated: true) {
        popoverPresentation.passthroughViews = nil
    }

}

private func configurePresentation(from contentVC: PopoverContentType, preferredWidth: CGFloat) -> UIPopoverPresentationController? {
    let height = contentVC.getHeight()
    contentVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: preferredWidth, height: height)

    contentVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

    guard let popOverPresentation = contentVC.popoverPresentationController else {
        return nil
    }

    popOverPresentation.permittedArrowDirections = .up

    return popOverPresentation

}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I using the following approach, but not sure is this the best way.

```
protocol ShowPopoverProtocol {
func showPopover<Content: PopoverBaseContent, Target>(contentVc:Content, on target: Target, preferredWidth: CGFloat, arrowDirection: UIPopoverArrowDirection)
}
```

using `generic function` instead of `associated type`.